# AWS Amplify (GraphQL) - Using "graphqlOperation" vs Normal Query?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify

Might be a simple question, but I initially have been using the `graphqlOperation` for API queries in AWS Amplify. Recently I started utilizing Cognito User Pools. For the life of me, I could not pass `authMode` into it and ended up using a normal query.

```
## normal query - works
await API.graphql({query: listForms, authMode: 'AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS'});

## using graphqlOperation - does not work (Unauthorized)
await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listForms,  { authMode: 'AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS' }));
```

I'm ok with using the normal query but I'm wondering why you'd use the `graphqlOperation` class at all if the normal query seems to suffice? They both seem to return the same payload. Most documentation seems to reference using `graphqlOperation`. I'm just not sure what benefit it brings.

Thanks!
T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use graphqlOperation with authMode. Use just API.graphql() instead.

"Previous examples uses graphqlOperation function. That function only creates an object with two attributes query and variables. In order to use authMode you need to pass this object as is mentioned on the previous example."

See [Configure authorization modes](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/authz/q/platform/js#using-amplify-graphql-client)

Answer (score 1):

Docs don't mention it, but you can simply do this. Works for me.

```
      await API.graphql({
        ...graphqlOperation(createTodo, { input: todo }),
        authMode: "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons to use graphqlOperation is in the case your method listMessages has any parameters you could pass those in the call of graphqlOperation(listMessages, {...params})

Comment: Can you give an example of a request that wouldn't work with the object-query syntax?